# WCF service implemented in Silverlight using Windows Phone App ? Any pointers

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, unity-container, mef

Can WCF/MEF/Unity be implemented in Silverlight using Windows Phone App ? Any pointers

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about WCF or MEF, but the Unity team just [announced Windows Phone 8 support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2013/08/29/unity-di-container-now-supports-windows-phone.aspx) for Unity.